# Badge photos that are geotagged

Tags: nautilus, geolocation

I want to know if my photos are Geo-tagged.

Is there an app or plugin that will badge these in Nautilus? ...or perhaps show the tag in list details?

Comment: You might want to have a look at this: http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/76-gnome/349-gnome-nautilus-exif-iptc-xmp-gps-column-property-extension